# How to expire a web-page immediately

Tags: php, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a web page and I want to immediately expire it after loading, so If user wants to see my page code he should face with an error like this:

> **Document Expired**
>
> *This document is no longer available.*

To accomplish this idea, I set the following header on my page:

```
<?php header("Expires: " . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() - 3600)); ?>
```

But seems it's not working correctly, any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Are you trying to protect your web site code ?

Comment: The HTTP expires header controls how your browser caches entities. That's why this approach wont work. Sadly, i don't know if what you're trying to do is possible with PHP only. Reference: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html section 14.21

Answer (score 2):

"Document Expired" header inform browser do not cache page or flush cache, but do not protect from viewing page source.

Comment: Yup, you're right - However is there any way to implement "Document Expired"?

Comment: You can implement what you want only if your server will send "Document Expired" as page content in response.

My opinion that the juice is not worth the squeeze.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop the User from browsing through your code, if he is knowledgeable. At best you can obfuscate your code using javascript tools like [Htmlguardian](http://www.htmlguardian.org/help_main.html).

But any user with some knowhow can completely restore the code since the Browser must parse your page to display it.

Answer (score 0):

By doing that you are telling to the browser to stop caching your html document it self. In reality there is no way to protect your HTML/JS/CSS code.

There are several services that obfuscating JS/HTML but still your code is not safe. Anything comes into your computer belongs to you, it suffices to find the way to use it.

Anything comes into your computer, it is inside your computer, images, html, js, css, videos,  audio, anything.

If you can find the way to use that data, then you can own that data.